Why does my KDE make such a mess when coming back?
I want to do a bunch of tasks before and after the screensaver is activated in KDE (still using X11, since Wayland has too many flaws even after 10 years).
So I made a custom script that is triggered after 5 minutes of inactivity (KDE settings > Power Management > Other Settings).
The problem: when I come back and press a key, KDE takes around 8 seconds to show the desktop, and when it does, it is not quite ready, turns the screen off/on, moves things around, blinks, etc, during around 6 to 8 seconds more until it is finally back from the Dead. Probably that consumes more energy than keeping the screen on!
This is my script:
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2
xset dpms force off

If instead of the xset line I put the next line the problem persists:
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.kde.kglobalaccel \
  /component/org_kde_powerdevil org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut \
  string:'Turn Off Screen'

So: why is KDE making such a mess, and how can I prevent it?
Or maybe there is a better way to do this? I would love to know your own way.

@terdon Please see my edit.

Thanks, that makes things much clearer (but also much weirder, I have no clue what could cause this given that very simple script).
